# Where to get the list of org-mode commands as lisp variables?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, keymap

After so much research, I managed to get `alt + RET` working. Learned so much!

I appended to my ~/.emacs:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (if window-system
            nil
          (progn
            (define-key org-mode-map "\C-\M-j" 'org-meta-return)
            (define-key org-mode-map "\C-j" 'org-insert-heading-respect-content\
)))))
```

I want to remap more things, like `alt + right arrow`. To do so, I could just add more `(define-key org-mode-map` ... blocks, but:

Where can I get the list of commands such as `'org-meta-return` to create my mappings?

Comment: How about (?) in an org-mode buffer typing, `M-x describe-mode` and read about all the keybindings or how about looking at the variable `org-mode-map` by typing `M-x describe-variable RET org-mode-map RET`  You can also grep the source code for `org-mode-map`.  There are other maps you may also be interested in such as the `org-agenda-mode-map` if you use the agenda buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `org` <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Then copy paste the commands from the pop-up window. There are hundreds of them though, so good luck with that.

To get a list of the commands that are currently bound to a key, press <kbd>C-h m</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks so much! That, in addition with @lawlist comment are what I was looking for. :)